# Linear algebra: Null space Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Suppose I have a matrix $A_{3\times 3}$ then if my rank of column space is 1 then rank of null space is 2. Is there anyway I can get the basis vectors of null space from this matrix A itself?

Comment: The Gauss Elimination process for solving equations is a sure and certain way to calculate a basis of the kernel.

Comment: @ancientmathematician.: This question was asked to get an answer to another problem I guess. Can you check my latest question once?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3715772/vectors-spanning-nullspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as *the* basis vectors of the null space, since there are infinitely many such bases. Simply solve the system$$A.\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$and find a basis of the space of solutions.

Comment: So given a matrix $A$ we can never get to know the basis vectors of null space without solving it right? (Any basis vectors of nullspace). Maybe I will just share with you the exact statement that is written in the slides and you will understand it better.

Comment: I am unaware of any other method that works for every $3\times3$ matrix.

Comment: We have an equation of the form $XE=0$. Now we have $8\times9$ matrix $X$ and a vector $E$. In case rank of $X$ is 8 we get a unique solution for $E$. Then if we change E to be $7 \times 9$ then we can have $rank (X)=7$ atmost. But at this point if we know $det(E)=0$, we can get two vectors $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ (the nullspace of $X$ will have dimension atleast 2 spanned by two vectors $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$). Then we can solve for E by determining $\alpha$ such that $det E = det(E_{1} + \alpha E_{2})=0$. Can you explain this last part please?  This is actually referring to the 8 point algorithm.

Comment: That is another question. I suggest that you post it as such.

Comment: Ok. I will do that now